# Browser memory increases issue with 6 ajax call every second

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have my page in mvc which call 6 ajax request every second from javascript contineously and application is running 24/7 and after sometime memory get increasing and crash the application.I tried all the option that removing setinterval, makeing data null in success but it wont work. Can anyone help me for this queries.

Comment: have you considered signalR ? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr

Comment: You apparently have a memory leak.  We can't help you without your code, though.

Comment: what kind of data is returned?

Comment: I would suggest that you look into websockets, one of their use cases is to solve the issue that you are raising here.